# Adding bulky capacitor vs multiple parallel capacitors on Boost converter's output

Tags: capacitor, boost

[image: schematic]
For VOUT, I noticed you can add capacitors in parallel to handle voltage ripples.

If all capacitors are populated, it will be

10+10+10+100 = 130 uF

I wish to compare

- populating all 4 capacitors (20% tolerance, 35V rating) VS
- populating a single capacitor, like 150uF [EEE-FTV151XAP (20% tolerance, 35V rating)](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-electronic-components/EEE-FTV151XAP/PCE5017CT-ND/2652072)

Is there a big difference between these two?

Comment: I suggest that you have a look at the datasheets and compare some properties of 10 uF, 100 uF and 150 uF capacitors. Instead of paying attention to tolerance and voltage rating, look at **ESR** (equivalent series resistance) and **resonance frequency** The 10 uF caps might have a higher ESR but there are 3 in parallel and there's a 100 uF cap as well. How does that compare to the ESR of a single 150 uF cap?

Comment: Those caps are almost certainly for noise filtering. Replacing them with 1 bigger cap would be a terrible idea. Though you may not really **need** three 10 uF, one might do the trick. But who ever designed it thinks you need three.